# Proportions (and using abstract terms to define them)

Tags: linear-algebra

If $r:s = 3:7$, then $r:3 = k$, where $k$ is a proportion comparing $s$ to a number.

I initially tried $$\frac rs = \frac 37 \\ \frac r3 = \frac 37$$ ...here I was able to simplify $r$ to $\frac 97$, but that doesn't answer the question at hand.

What am I missing? How can I incorporate $s$ in my answer?

Comment: How do $r,s$ relate to $x,y$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Clarified my question; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$r/s=3/7 \\
r\cdot 7= 3\cdot s \\
r/3=s/7$$

Comment: **smacks head** duh! Don't know what I was thinking.